# Как использовать карту слово значение и посчитать вхождение слов

Tags: java

Как использовать `map` для подсчета вхождении слов из `System.in`?

Comment: например использовать в качестве "значения" число раз которое используется слово

Answer (score 0):

Так должно прокатить

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+", Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Map<String, Integer> counters = new TreeMap<>();
        while (scanner.hasNext(wordPattern)) {
            String word = scanner.next(wordPattern);
            if (!counters.containsKey(word)) {
                counters.put(word, 1);
            } else {
                counters.put(word, counters.get(word) + 1);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : counters.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" +  entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

PS: тут не приветствуются вопросы в стиле "сделайте за меня домашку". В следующий раз присылайте свой неработающий код, чтобы было видно, что вы сами что-то пытаетесь делать.